# Why canvas objects are re-scaled when using CSS to style width and dimensions?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I'm following a JS canvas tutorial and tried to play with the canvas properties and found this scenario, if the canvas width and height are styled in-line, the objects look fine, but when removing the in-line properties, and use CSS to set the same width and height, the object drawn in the canvas are resized/scaled, any idea why? Links to documentation are appreciated

For example:

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320">
The browser does not support Canvas
</canvas>
```

changes when used as:

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas">
The browser does not support Canvas
</canvas>
```

```css
#myCanvas {
  width: 480px;
  height: 320px;
}
```

The object drawn is stretched as:
https://ibb.co/TmKhbgb

Looks like the canvas should keep a proportion ratio 2:1 (rectangular) when CSS is used to set up its dimensions

Comment: oops, selected the wrong duplicate ... will recrtify

Comment: updated the link

Comment: Thanks, will read it right now